# cat bash command to convert tab to comma delimited and wrap in double quotes

Tags: bash, csv

I have the following data (as an example)

```
name    street    suburb
Todd Man    14 Streety Road    Townsville
Cheryl Lady 15 Roady Street    Villatown
Girl, Sara  16 Circus Circuit  Groundston
```

and using this command to convert from a tab seperated to comma seperated csv

```
cat customers.csv | tr '[\t]' '[,]' > customers_comma.csv
```

The output is then

```
name,street,suburb
Todd Man,14 Streety Road,Townsville
Cheryl Lady,15 Roady Street,Villatown
Girl, Sara,16 Circus Circuit,Groundston
```

But `Girl, Sara` is adding in an extra column. How can I make it so the output is

`name,street,suburb
 Todd Man,14 Streety Road,Townsville
 Cheryl Lady,15 Roady Street,Villatown
 "Girl, Sara",16 Circus Circuit,Groundston`

Seems simple enough but have Googled the hell out of this and can't find a solution.

I don't have to use `cat` but would like if there was a one line bash command to do it.

Comment: Bash is not great for string manipulation. You'll end up with an ugly `sed` or `awk` line. If you expect to reuse this script, a `python` one-liner will be much more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little awk solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS=",";Q="\""}
          {for (i=1;i<=NF;++i)
             if ($i ~ /[",]/)
               $i = Q gensub(/"/,Q Q,"g",$i) Q
          }
          {$1 = $1}
     1' file.txt
```

It also doubles quotes if one is found in a field.

Comment: Thank you rici! I have applied this answer to my actual file and it works like a dream. Sorry I have marked the other as the answer but it answers my simplified version. Huge kudos to you from me though. Champion.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below sed command.

```
$ sed 's/\([^[:space:],]\+, *[^[:space:]]\+\)/"\1"/g;s/\t/,/g' file
name,street,suburb
Todd Man,14 Streety Road,Townsville
Cheryl Lady,15 Roady Street,Villatown
"Girl, Sara",16 Circus Circuit,Groundston
```

where `[^[:space:],]\+` matches any character but not of a space or comma one or more times.

Comment: Thank you. This works. As usual though, I have simplified my question. The answer works but when I apply it to my larger file it is acting different. This at least gives me a start so thank you.